# Docker run command without -it option

Tags: docker, containers

Why when i run the command

```
docker run ubuntu
```

without option '-it' is not possible to interact with the created container even when running command start with the -a -i options

```
docker start -a -i CONTAINER_ID
```

or when i run

```
docker start CONTAINER_ID
```

simply the container has the status "Exit (0) 4 seconds ago"

But when i run

```
docker run -it ubuntu
```

i can use bash shell of ubuntu using 'docker start -a -i'

Answer (score 8):

When you run `docker run` without `-it` it's still running the container but you've not given it a command, so it finishes and exits.

If you try:

```sh
docker run ubuntu /bin/bash -c "echo 'hello'";
```

It'll run ubunu, then the command, and then finish because there is no reason for it to be kept alive afterwards.

`-i` is saying keep it alive and work within in the terminal (allow it to be interactive), but if you type `exit`, you're done and the container stops.

`-t` is showing the terminal of within the docker container (see: **[What are pseudo terminals (pty/tty)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21149/421598)**)

`-it` allows you to see the terminal in the docker instance and interact with it.

Additionally you can use `-d` to run it in the background and then get to it afterwards.

Ex:

```sh
docker run -it -d --name mydocker ubuntu;
docker exec -it mydocker /bin/bash;
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR is `-it` allows you connect a terminal to interactively connect to the container.

If you run `docker run --help`, you can find the details about `docker run` options.

```
$ docker run --help

Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Run a command in a new container

Options:
  ...
  -i, --interactive                    Keep STDIN open even if not attached
  ...
  -t, --tty                            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```